# Redirect Local Port to Outside Network using Nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect my `http://127.0.0.1:9090/data/admin/` to `http://94.162.152.12:9090/admin/` that can be access outside in my network. I already open port 9090 in my router.

Take a look my nginx config

```
 server {
    listen 9090;
    server_name 94.162.152.12;

      location ~* /data/admin/ {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9090;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean proxying from `http://94.162.152.12:9090/admin/` to `http://127.0.0.1:9090/data/admin/` you might want to do it as follow:

```
server {
    listen 9090;
    server_name 94.162.152.12;

      location /admin {
          rewrite               ^/admin/(.*) https://127.0.0.1:443/data/admin/$1 permanent;
          proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:9090;
          proxy_redirect        off;
          proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header      Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header      X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }

 }
```

This will rewrite all requests for /admin/* to /data/admin/* and call localhost as backend.